# what is the geometric interpretation of cauchy's integral theorem?

Tags: complex-analysis

I know the definition that if *f(z)* is analytic * f'(z)** is continuous at all points inside and on the boundary of a simple closed curve *C* then, ∫f(z) dz=0.
but geometrically or physically its not clear to me?
if one can explain with some simple curves i'll appreciate that.